# JQuery: Live <a> tag partially working second time around

Tags: jquery

I have the following jquery code:

```
$("a[id*='Add_']").live('click', function() {
    //Get parentID to add to.
    var parentID = $(this).attr('id').substring(4);

    //Get div.
    var div = $("#CreateList");

    //Ajax call to refresh "CreateList" div with new unordered list.
    div.load("/AddUnit?ParentID=" + parentID);
});
```

Basically, contained within the div is a nested unordered list with several "Add_#" links. Clicking the links uses an ajax call to recreate the list with a new node. It clears all the add links, but they are added again by the ajax call. This is why I used the .live method so newly added "Add_#" links still have the binding.

This works in most cases. If I click "Add_1", the div refreshes with the new info. If I then click "Add_2", it works again as expected.

The problem I'm having happens when I click "Add_1", then the page refreshes (and creates a new "Add_1" link), then I click the re-rendered "Add_1" again. It's the same link, but it was refreshed during the ajax call. When I do that, the javascript function still gets called, but the .load method doesn't work. Any ideas why this might be happening? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the add is getting re-created with the right `Add_#` ID scheme?  Or...is the load not firing at all?

Comment: Yeah, the same rendering component is used to render the page initially as well as the ajax calls. I put an "alert(parentID);" line after the "div.load" line, and the function still gets called. The function still gets called every time, but there is never a request sent to "AddUnit" (confirmed with fiddler).

Comment: Note that .live doesn't bind to the <a> elements but to the document itself, so it sounds like something else is going on here, like Nick suggested (as removing and adding the <a> elements should have no impact on whether the event handler is called unless the <a> tag does not match the selector of the live event).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the result's being cached, to resolve that, force jQuery to make the request in a way that doesn't cache.  Add this before all your method calls to do just that:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

You can see [`$.ajaxSetup()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) and [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for details.